# Redirect from index and to index page. Is it possible?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I'm updating a website. I installed wordpress in the root, and contained the old websited in a folder. My client however wants to see the old website on the main domain, and the new one in another url, to check on developement.

Is it possible to set up a "cross referencing" .htaccess redirect? Main domain redirecting to the "old" folder, a made up url redirecting to the main domain - and staying there.
This is my two relevant .htaccess line so far. The problem is, the second line gets redirected.

```
Redirect /index.php http://example.com/old/
Redirect /wordpress.php http://example.com/
```

Other ideas are appreciated as well. Sorry if the actual solution will get out of topic, but I feel that explaining the situation was required.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This will create an infinite loop .. Why don't you just copy the files to a subfolder and replace the 'old' website to the root?

Comment: It's not infinite, it'll arrive at "http://example.com/old". Developement for the new wp site is already in progress with several files and configuration. I don't want to risk wordpress messing up image, link and other urls after two moving (to /tmp folder and when finished, back to root).

Comment: when you enter example.com, it show default page (/index.php or .html or whatever main default page). with ur .htaccess code, it will not create any infinite loop, but if you got to /wordpress.php it will send you to example.com/old/ url. :) oopsi

Comment: no, it's not an infinite loop, and yes, I know the second line will arrive to /old, same as index. That wasn't the question.

I've decided to move the folders, as there doesn't seem to be a .htaccess redirect workaround. It would be nice to see a final confirmation on the topic though.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the domain in the htaccess, and when it is the old domain you redirect to the old folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?olddomain.com$
RewriteRule !^old/ /old%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```